# How to execute PHPUnit?

Tags: php, xml, report, phpunit

PHPUnit can execute script like this:

`phpunit --log-junit classname filename.php`

(i need the XML report , for my continuous integreation platform)

but my problem is that i work with a MVC  framework and all pages are called through `pathofproject/indexCLI.php module=moduleName class=className` ect with 3 arguments in total(when i use the shell commande and path/index.php argum=... with url) so i cant call
phpunit pathofproject/indexCLI.php module=moduleName class=className .

So i think to a lot of solution , i hope you can help me to use one of them.

1. first how can i use phpunit command with this type of calling, because i cant do it because it is waiting for a classname and a filename (default comportement) if it possible !!
2. when i call the same link in shell
   like this : php path/indexCLI.php module="blabla" ect ...
   i have the result of assertion in my console , but cant use XML Junit option , can i do it ?
3. my last solution is to call the link in a navigator like mozilla , but i dont know how to tell phpunit runner to choose XML report and not HTML report.

the aim for me , is to have a XML report .

Comment: Did you try using the phpunit.xml and specifying your log options there?

Comment: Your projects CLI has nothing to do with your unit tests. It looks like you're looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Do you want to test low-level items (say, input X to a function produces output Y), or do you want to test the operation of your whole web app? If the latter, you probably want to add functional tests that perform operations on your website (log on, click button X, check output via regex, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests are created to test "units", functions. So you must pass to phpUnit name of file where the class you want to test is. Nothing else. If you want to test how is your whole system is working, you need something like [functional testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_Testing)

Comment: I agree, I feel the user fundamentally misunderstands how unittests are supposed to work.

Comment: @Evert, that's why they've approached S/O. Maybe offer some help? `:)`

Comment: i cant make a answer to explain more , thats sux

Comment: i will explain more,

how you will test your class ?
like that

    class test extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
    public function setUp()
    {
    $this->_instance =new ExempkOfClass();
    }
    
    }
    
    public function testTest()
    {
    $this->assertTrue($this->_instance->functionExemple($input));
    }

Comment: thats is an axemple. okey but my problem with my framework is that i cant use the NEW keyword i need to use a framework function like

    $this->_instance=_class(moduleName|className);

and when i use phpunit commande in my sheel he cant understand and make a link with the function and framework , unlike php commande , because with php commande he make a link betwen this function to creat a new object and the framework

for any question , telle me pls 

thnks for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bootstrap parts of your application, which maybe is why you are trying to run your tests through your cli script, you should separate out the bootstrapping into a separate file and get phpunit to call it for each test by adding it to the phpunit.xml file. http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: sorry , i cant understande the bootstrapping file, but just try to understand me

Comment: if you want test class MyClass you need to have 
$object= new Myclass();
alright ?
i work with a framework so i cant use the keyword "new" , i use a function from the framework _class() so when i call 
phpunit Myscript 
he cant understand _class function
you see what is my problem ?

Comment: yeh you need to make a script that sets up all the requirements to be able to call _class(). Then get phpunit to execute that each time, using the xml config. Sounds like a strange framework. Why can't you call new?

Comment: thats may be a solution , but how i will do to call all framwwork classes ? i need a lot of include. i tried __autoload() but not working .

and finaly i can use new ,sure XD but for exemple i will make new for classe , but this class call other ones and other ones and they are called with _class() function , so is not the solution thats why i say i cant use new keyword . you see what i mean ?

Comment: You dont call the framework dependencies in xml, set them up in a php file, the xml file is just config for phpunit, you set your boostrap, and phpunit calls it for each test to set up the environment you need.  You can set the boostrap file from the commandline too.  "phpunit --bootstrap {file.php}". http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/textui.html.

Comment: If you cant do this easily, maybe you should consider functional tests as said above. Use something like Selenium or Behat.

Comment: thnks for the anwser , i understand now that i need a bootstrap file, thats a good news ,

at the moment , i need just an example for this file to understand how its work , and how i can write one for my application.
thnks

Comment: i think if i have an exemple , i will understand , come on guys a good example plz XD

Comment: I can't really give you an example, as it is entirely dependant on your framework. Figure out what it is doing in indexCLI.php and go from there.